# Show widget based on firestore database document existance

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm completely new to flutter mobile development.
What I want to achieve is to have an authenticated user (in the app) that is also connected to an Instagram account. I use Firebase for authentication and also Cloud Firestore Database. My idea is the following:

- Authenticate the user using the authentication service in Firebase, once authenticated I'll have a unique UID like in the following picture: [user entry in authentication service in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvXCJ.png)
- Add a document in the Firestore database with the same UID of the authenticated user and also other data related to the Instagram account once the user has connected the instagram account and set up some preferences.

To do that in the app I've implemented this simple code in the main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide EmailAuthProvider;
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';

import 'package:main/routingPage.dart';

/// create firestore instace to use in the rest of the code
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

void main() async{
  /// Initialize Firebase
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  /// Run app
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
       home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              /// If the user is not logged in, I ask him to log in or subscribe
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return SignInScreen(
                  providers: [
                    EmailAuthProvider(),
                  ],
                );
              }
              /// If the user is logged in I proceed on the routingPage
              else {
                return routingPage();
              }
            },
       )
    );
  }
}
```

After authentication, (in this case in the routing page, but I don't know if this is the correct approach) I need to do a simple operation: check if a document with the same UID of the authenticated user already exists in the Firestore Database or not.

- if the document exist proceed on the principal page of the app.
- if the document does not exist send the user to a guided procedure to connect its instagram and select some preferences, create the document and then go back to the principal page.

Now it is two days that I'm completely stuck. I don't know how to implement it effectively, if this is the right way to do it, if there are leaner implementations and so on.

What I would like to get help on is at the architecture level since I don't require just a log in but also a log in + Instagram connection. How would you proceed? What is the best way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
First off, thank you for the great formatting/styling of the question. But please note that these types of questions on "how to implement it effectively" or "correct architecture" are considered as off-topic for this site.

Comment: Thank you MendelG. Do you know where I can find answers on this type of questions? I'm going crazy about this

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question: your code with a `StreamBuilder` and `snapshot.hasData` looks fine at first glance. Isn't it working? If not, is there an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally how I would approach it would be to send the user to a splash screen, so, `home` will be `SplashScreen`, then on the splashScreen's `initState`, we call the function that starts the checking future, with a `.then` push to the appropriate screen

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  // This function will be somewhere else(for architecture's sake)
  Future<bool> checkIfUserExists({
    required FirebaseAuth auth,
    required FirebaseFirestore store,
  }) async {
    if (auth.currentUser == null) return false;
    final userDoc =
        await store.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).get();
    return userDoc.exists;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkIfUserExists(
      auth: FirebaseAuth.instance,
      store: FirebaseFirestore.instance,
    ).then((userExists) {
      if(userExists) return Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
    });
    // When you take them to login, over there, you will use the auth 
    // instance to log them in and after that, 
    // FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser will no longer be null, then you'll 
    // fetch the user's data from the Firestore with their currentUser.uid.
    
    // For sign-up, after they sign-up, you go ahead and create a document 
    // for them using their uid
    
    // await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth
    //     .instance.currentUser!.uid).set({
    //   'userName': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName,
    //   // ... and so on
    // });
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build your splash screen here
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Comment: You welcome mate, and again, Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

To check is that document exist or not you have to:

1. fetch that document
2. use `.exist` property

kindly check the below example, hope this help

```
/// after login check is user document exist or not
Future<void> getUserFromFirestore() async {
  final String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
  final DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc().get();

  if (snapshot.exists) {
    // navigate to home
  } else {
    // navigate to registration page
  }
}
```

and don't forget to save user data to firestore after login/registration

```
/// save data after login/registration
Future<void> saveUserToFirestore() async {
  final String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

  // if you want to update data use update instead of set
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uid).set({ 
    // your data here
    "name": "user name",
  });
}
```

feel free to ask